# using flask make application need for assignment otherwise I will fail :(

Tags: python, integer

Using the Flask microframework, create a web application that takes a positive integer in the web form field and determines which is the minimum natural divisor of this number (except 1).
For example: the number 8 is included, the program should display 2 on a separate html page, if 9 is the answer: 3, or if it is 13, the answer will be: 13.

Comment: Hi Ako, welcome to stack overflow. The site is intended to help with specific programming questions rather than complete assignments - could you post your current attempt to solve the problem and indicate where the code is not working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

You need to break down your assignment into smaller bits.

1. Create a [basic Flask app](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/)
2. Create a [basic webform](https://pythonspot.com/flask-web-forms/) using Flask.
3. Create logic to get the lowest natural divisor.

The third one is not that hard:

```py
def get_lowest_divisor(input: int) -> int:
    for i in range(2, input):
        if (input % i == 0):
            return i
    return input

print(get_lowest_divisor(8))
print(get_lowest_divisor(9))
print(get_lowest_divisor(13))
```

The output of this is:

```
2
3
13
```

The trick here is to check if the remainder of the division is 0. Check [this link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-python-modulo-operator-what-does-the-symbol-mean-in-python-solved/) for explanation.

Problems/questions get a lot easier if you break them down into smaller problems/questions, which is something to remember for next homework assignments. I would rather fight 100 duck-sized horses than one horse-sized duck.

[image: I would rather fight 100 duck-sized horses than one horse-sized duck.]

Also, just google the eff out of your questions. Good [Googling skills](https://xkcd.com/979/) are absolutely needed if you want to do coding.